# Error with a client web service in java: [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.resolver.JBossWSResourceResolver] Cannot open stream for resource

Tags: java, jboss

I had an application in production running perfectly for 2 years and it stopped working a web client, but the URL that my client is consuming on the internet is published and working well. I realized that if I change the URL to http the web client already works. But with https it doesn't work. The contracts are the same. I don't understand why it doesn't work with https. It´s the only that change.

this is the URL that stopped working in my code

```
URL strEndPoint      = new URL("https://ws.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl");
```

this is the URL that does work

```
URL strEndPoint      = new URL("http://ws.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl");
```

I need it to work with https for security policies

```
URL strEndPoint= new URL("https://ws.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl");
```

---

```
    System.out.println("PP: Create Web Service Client...");
    LuhnChecker service = new LuhnChecker(strEndPoint);
    System.out.println("PP: Create Web Service...");
```

---

```
15:28:33,139 WARN  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.resolver.JBossWSResourceResolver] Cannot open stream for resource: https://ws.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl
15:28:35,855 ERROR [STDERR] javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:152)

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:71)

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.cdyne.ws2.LuhnChecker.<init>(LuhnChecker.java:48)

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at co.com.pulxar.validar.luhnTarjetas.checkLuhn(luhnTarjetas.java:35)

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at co.com.pulxar.ws.WS_PasarelaPagoImpl.ValidarTarjeta(WS_PasarelaPagoImpl.java:232)

15:28:35,856 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

15:28:35,857 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

15:28:35,857 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

15:28:35,857 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

15:28:35,857 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.wsf.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0):

The differences between the two URLs are the protocol.

The one that stopped working:

```
URL strEndPoint      = new URL("https://ws.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl");
```

```
URL strEndPoint      = new URL("http://ws.cdyne.com/creditcardverify/luhnchecker.asmx?wsdl");
```

As explained on this [thread](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/224406), you can fix is setting `secureSocketProtocol="TLSv1"` in  in my cxf.xml file, which is mandatory.